# Выдаёт ошибку not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу прогу в питоне, выдает вот такую фигню.

```
print('Введите первое число')
a = input()
print('Введите второе число')
b = input()
print('Введите третье число')
f = input()
print('Введите четвертое число')
d = input()
print('Введите пятое число')
e = input()
числа = []
if((a%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(a)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((b%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(b)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((f%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(f)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((d%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(d)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((e%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):`введите сюда код`
    числа.append(e)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
print(len(числа))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TheArtemius\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\2.py", line 12, in 
if((a%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Где я накасячил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед каждым `input` поставьте приведение к `int`, потому что `input`-ы возвращают строки, а не числа:

```
print('Введите первое число')
a = int(input())
print('Введите второе число')
b = int(input())
print('Введите третье число')
f = int(input())
print('Введите четвертое число')
d = int(input())
print('Введите пятое число')
e = int(input())
числа = []
if((a%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(a)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((b%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(b)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((f%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(f)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((d%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(d)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
if((e%4 == 0) and (a%7 !=0)):
    числа.append(e)
else:
    print('Число не делиться на 4')
print(len(числа))
```